# query mobile code javascript working in browser desktop but not in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

i have a problem with my code.
all works fine in browser desktop but in mobile i must to click on the div #Resultat to show the result. please tell me what's wrong with my code.
i put a [url](http://domainedelavillerouge.fr/.jqm/) because in jsfiddle it's works but it's not that i want .

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).delegate('#so2', 'pagebeforeshow', function(){       
    $(document).bind('click', '[data-role="controlgroup"]', function(){ 
    setTimeout(function () {displayVals(); },100);
    });
    $("#Resultat").on('click', function(event, ui) {
    displayVals();
    });
    function displayVals() {
    var so2Present = $("#so2present").val();
    var so2Voulu = $("#so2voulue").val();
    var volume = $("#volume").val();
    var unite = $("input[name='Unit']:checked").val();
    //var forme = $("input[name='Form']:checked").val();
    var summary = parseFloat(((so2Voulu - so2Present)*volume *1.5)*unite).toPrecision(3);
    $("#Resultat").html(summary); 
}
    });
</script>


<div data-role="page" id="so2">


            <div data-role="header" class="jqm-header" style="padding-top:20px; background:#4d4d4d;">
                <a href="#defaultpanel" class="navmenu-link" id="menu" style="margin-top:19px;" title="Navigation"></a>

            </div><!--/ header -->
            <div data-role="content">

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="slider" class="so2present">SO2 présent:</label></br>
    <input type="range" name="slider1" id="so2present" value="0" min="0" max="50" step="1" data-highlight="true" />
            <p></p>
        <label for="slider" class="so2voulue">SO2 voulue:</label></br>
    <input type="range" name="slider2" id="so2voulue" value="0" min="0" max="50" step="1" data-highlight="true" />
            <p></p>
        <label for="slider" class="volume">Volume:</label></br>
    <input type="range" name="slider1" id="volume" value="0" min="0" max="250" step="1" data-highlight="true" />
             <div >
                 <div id="Resultat" class="ui-body ui-body-d ui-corner-all"></div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="unite">
            <input type="radio" name="Unit" id="Unit_0" value="1" />
            <label for="Unit_0">ML</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Unit" id="Unit_1" value="0.001" />
            <label for="Unit_1">L</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Unit" id="Unit_2" value="0.01" />
            <label for="Unit_2">G</label>
          </div>
          </div><!--/fieldcontain-->
       </div><!--/unite-->
                         </div><!--/content-->

        </div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Does it help if you default one of the radio buttons to checked: <input type="radio" name="Unit" id="Unit_0" value="1" checked="true" />

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved i have changed the version of jquery and jquery mobile  for the .js
now, just the little problem is when you change the value of sliders you must click 2x in the input to see the result updated.